# ElasticSearch NEST issue with ingesting PDFs

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to index some PDF documents using NEST and ElasticSearch 5.1. Most of them go thru fine. The larger ones (10 MB to 40 MB) throw either a "(413) Request Entity Too Large" or "System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Can somebody please help me figure out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this in case somebody else runs into this issue.

It turned out that the issue is due to the Network limitations on the AWS instance. We were using a micro instance and the maximum HTTP request payload for it is 10 MB. Changing the instance type to xlarge solved the issue. Here is a listing of the AWS instance types and the maximum payloads:

[AWS Elasticsearch Network limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html#network-limits)